# doxygen with IDL/ODL

Tags: c++, com, doxygen, idl

If you have a C++ project that has a bunch of .ODL files *and* the generated .h files from the ODL compiler, should doxygen be told to parse both .odl and .h, or only one or the other? In general I don't like documenting generated code but IDL is sort of a special case.

In any case, it seems like the member listing of ODL files is not quite working properly in my tests, are ODL files properly parsed?

Answer (score 3):

From [this page](http://www.doxygen.nl/starting.html) it seems the Doxygen perfectly supports parsing `*idl` and `*.odl` files. Maybe you have some issues regarding the comments format ?

Anyway, I would advise you against parsing both `*.idl/*.odl` files and generated `.h` files. The latter are, by definition, generated and represent the same classes than the one defined in the `*.idl/*.old` files.

Parsing both is like documenting the same set of classes twice, which is obviously not a good idea.

Comment: That was my initial thought... but what happens with classes using these interfaces... they include the .h files so wouldn't that mean a 'gap' in the chain?

Comment: I'm not sure about the comment format, I have it set to generate everything even if there are no source-comments (we're doxygenating an existing project). I get a link to "xxx.odl" but clicking on it doesn't show me the file's source like with .h files.

Comment: @John: I doubt Doxygen can generate links to generated files (aka. files it did **not** parse itself). About the "gap" in the chain: i guess it's just a way of seeing things ;) Imo, it is perfectly fine to think that some not-generated classes use generated files. There is no real "gap" here: just an additional "link" (the "generation").